# Loop to create copies

Tags: macos, bash, for-loop

I'm making a bash script on an OSX computer at work to create a kit of prints.
The script works fine, as it make the correct amount of copies of the files to the correct destination.

However the destination, a 'print rip', serves the files with a 'first in - first out' principle. My script seems to be making the copies of each file by the file. I want it to make a copy of the entire 'kit' of files, before proceeding to the next copy...

The order the script makes the copies now are:

```
File1-Copy1.jpg
File1-Copy2.jpg
File2-Copy1.jpg
File2-Copy2.jpg
```

The order I want the script to make the copies are:

```
File1-Copy1.jpg
File2-Copy1.jpg
File1-Copy2.jpg
File2-Copy2.jpg
```

My current script looks like this:

```
for filename in $(find $scriptdir -iname '*-F_*' -o -name '*.jpg' -print)
do
   for f in $(eval echo "{1..$copies}"); do 
       cp /$scriptdir/FILER/${filename##*/} $printdir"/"$PrintColor"_"$f"_"${filename##*/}; 
   done
done
```

So instead of copying each file X amount of times, before proceeding to the next file, I need the script to copy all the files, before proceeding to the next 'set' of files...

Does anyone have an idea of how to make it work?

Comment: `for i in {1..10};do for j in {1..10};do mv {dir,newdir}/"file$j-Copy$i";done;done` ?

Comment: Is there any way to do this with the cp command?
I can't get this working. Thanks though :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!
Thanks for your input, guys...

I changed the code to the following:

```
for setnumber in $(seq $copies); do
for filename in $(find $filesdir -iname '*-F_*' -o -name '*.jpg' -print)
do
cp $filesdir/${filename##*/} $printdir"/"$PrintColor"_SET"$setnumber"_"${filename##*/}; done
sleep 5
done
```

The sleep command is added just to make sure all the copies of the previous set has been created/timestamped, before proceeding to the next set....

Answer (score 1):

Use `sort`, for example:

```
for filename in $(find $scriptdir -name 'F*.jpg' -print|sort -t'/' -k2.11n)
do
    echo $filename
    base=${filename##*/}
    cp "filename" "$printdir/$PrintColor/$base"
done
```

Note that the sort uses field 2 (`-k2.11`) character 11 to sort on.  This assumes that there is just one leading directory name.  You might have to adjust this if your path is more complex.

Comment: Still not working :-/
However I realized I made a mistake, sorry. I forgot to write that the variabel $antal (now changed to $copies, is the number of sets I should print).

So the script gets input on the number of sets/copies it needs to make, and then it should make the files in the former written form...